# Using numpy.broadcast() on ndarray duck types

Tags: python, numpy, duck-typing

I've been trying to implement my own custom array container using [numpy's documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.dispatch.html) and I'm having trouble getting `numpy.broadcast()` to work with my container. I've defined `__array_function__` for my custom array container, but it isn't called when using `numpy.broadcast()`.

Is it correct that `numpy.broadcast()` doesn't use the `__array_function__` infrastructure? If so, is there any way to make a custom array container compatible with `numpy.broadcast`?